# php email form and canvas

Tags: javascript, php, canvas

As mentioned previously i have very little PHP knowledge so any help is much appreciated.

i have a working PHP script to handle my email form and i also have a working script to create my canvas image however i now need them to work together.

currently as stated i have 2 php files and very little PHP knowledge. file1.php - creates a canvas img thats stored on the server, canvas is designed on file canvas.html

and the file2.php - this emails my form data, form is on file form.html

now im needing them all to work like this...

e.g. user has designed product, now they fill in a form, at this point i need the cavas to do its thing and i need it to  run the form scripts.

sounds simple enough to me only everything im reading and trying isnt working, any help would be good.

this is my canvas code

```
<?

// set error reporting level
if (version_compare(phpversion(), '5.3.0', '>=') == 1)
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED);
else
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);

// save file
if ($_POST['data'] != '') {

$sRand = rand(100000, 999999);
$sOrigPath = 'cache/imagename'.$sRand.'.jpg';
@unlink($sOrigPath);

$img = $_POST['data'];
$img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
$img = str_replace('data:image/jpeg;base64,', '', $img);
$img = strip_tags($img);
$img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
$decodedData = base64_decode($img);

file_put_contents($sOrigPath, $decodedData);


$to =   'email@domain.com';
$subject =  ' ';
$bound_text =   "domain.com";
$bound =    "--".$bound_text."\r\n";
$bound_last =   "--".$bound_text."--\r\n";

$headers =  "From: email@domain.com\r\n";
$headers .=     "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"
."Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$bound_text\"";

$message .=     "If you can see this MIME than your client doesn't accept MIME types!\r\n"
.$bound;

$message .=     "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\r\n"
."Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n"
."hey my <b>good</b> friend here is a picture of regal beagle\r\n"
.$bound;

$file =     file_get_contents("$sOrigPath");     
$message .=     "Content-Type: image/jpg; name=\"imagename.jpg\"\r\n"
."Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n"
."Content-disposition: attachment; file=\"imagename.jpg\"\r\n"
."\r\n"
.chunk_split(base64_encode($file))
.$bound_last;

if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers))
{    echo $sOrigPath;

} else {
echo 'MAIL FAILED';
}


}
```

the code might be messy but like i said i don't know much but i know this creates what i need, then saves the jpg file to the server and emails it.

so now here is the email code

```
<?php
include("global.inc.php");
$errors=0;
$error="The following errors occured while processing your form input.<ul>";
pt_register('POST','firstname');
pt_register('POST','phone');
pt_register('POST','email');
pt_register('POST','message');
if($firstname=="" || $phone=="" || $email=="" || $message==""){
$errors=1;
$error.="<li>You did not enter one or more of the required fields. Please go back and     try again.";
}
if($errors==1) echo $error;
else{
$where_form_is="http".($HTTP_SERVER_VARS["HTTPS"]=="on"?"s":"")."://".$SERVER_NAME.strrev(strstr(strrev($PHP_SELF),"/"));
$message="Firstname: ".$firstname."
Phone: ".$phone."
Email: ".$email."  
Message: ".$message."
";
$message = stripslashes($message);
    mail("email@domain.com","Form Submitted at your website",$message,"From:     email@domain.com email form");
$make=fopen("admin/root.dat","a");
$to_put="";
$to_put .= $firstname."|".$phone."|".$email."|".$message."
";
fwrite($make,$to_put);

header("Refresh: 0;url=http://www.domain.com/thanks.html");
?><?php 
}
?>
```

i realize that as the scripts are they are trying to both send mail however I'm not sure ho i can make the final form. can it simply be done from file1.php ?

Comment: the first file is trying to send out an email (though the headers seem messed up) I dunno what are you exactly trying to achieve, but this is too messy, whatever you are upto. How are you trying to reach the second file you mentioned?

Comment: well thats the thing i dont have a clue. for instance it would be good f it can all be emailed from the first file however the canvas script isnt with the form

Comment: if you could write a clear headers you would be able to complete this from the first file itself. I doubt your second file is even being used, without seeing the rest of the code.